# How to chunk a list in Python 3?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I found the following code that is compatible with python2

```
from itertools import izip_longest
def grouper(n, iterable, padvalue=None):
  "grouper(3, 'abcdefg', 'x') --> ('a','b','c'), ('d','e','f'), ('g','x','x')"
  return izip_longest(*[iter(iterable)]*n, fillvalue=padvalue)
```

However, **this isn't working with Python 3**. I get the following error

```
ImportError: cannot import name izip_longest
```

Can someone help?

I'd like to convert my list of `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` to `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

### Edit

#### Now Python3 compatible

Code below is adapted from the selected answer. Simply change name from `izip_longest` to `zip_longest`.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def grouper(n, iterable, padvalue=None):
  "grouper(3, 'abcdefg', 'x') --> ('a','b','c'), ('d','e','f'), ('g','x','x')"
  return zip_longest(*[iter(iterable)]*n, fillvalue=padvalue)
```

Comment: Read the docs!  The Python 3 version of the `itertools` module documentation has the updated recipe for `grouper`:  http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In Python 3's `itertools` there is a function called `zip_longest`. It should do the same as `izip_longest` from Python 2.

Why the change in name? You might also notice that `itertools.izip` is now gone in Python 3 - that's because in Python 3, the `zip` built-in function now returns an iterator, whereas in Python 2 it returns a list. Since there's no need for the `izip` function, it also makes sense to rename the `_longest` variant for consistency.

Answer (score 3):

After all that discussion above, here's a python3 solution that I believe gives safer, more predicable results.

```
def chunker(iter, size):
    chunks = [];
    if size < 1:
        raise ValueError('Chunk size must be greater than 0.')
    for i in range(0, len(iter), size):
        chunks.append(iter[i:(i+size)])
    return chunks

example = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(' 1: ' + str(chunker(example, 1)))
print(' 3: ' + str(chunker(example, 3)))
print(' 4: ' + str(chunker(example, 4)))
print(' 8: ' + str(chunker(example, 8)))
print(' 9: ' + str(chunker(example, 9)))
print('10: ' + str(chunker(example, 10)))
```

The results are:

```
$ python3 iter_chunk.py 
 1: [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]
 3: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
 4: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9]]
 8: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9]]
 9: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
10: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> s = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> n = 3
>>> list(zip(*[iter(s)]*n))
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
```

Comment: Be aware that  `len(s) % n != 0` will result in missing members as the given recipe does not handle remainders. For example, `n = 8` will result in `[(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8)]`. Where's 9? In the same vein, :  `n > len(s)` will result in `[]`.

Comment: Would work by replacing zip with itertools.zip_longest as necesarry.

Comment: With  `n = 8` and itertools.zip_longest, we get`[(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8), (9, None, None, None)]`. We do get the 9 back, but now you must mitigate `None`s. And, with `n > len(s)` we are still left with `[]`. PHP's implementation of `array_chunk()` always seemed intuitive, where you get back (in Python parlance) for `n = 8`, `[(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8), (9)]` and for `n > len(s)` you get back the original array as the sole member of an outer array.  This way you always end up with something you can safely put through two nested loops without much caveating.

Comment: @JasonGabler: zip_longest has a `fillvalue` keyword argument that allows you to specify a fill value other than `None`.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
size = 4
chuck_list = [s[i:i+size] for i in range(0, len(s), size)]
```

Comment: New answers to old, well-answered questions should contain ample explanation on how they complement the other answers.

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score 0):

The source code of the `grouper()` function included in the question is copied from the documentation for `itertools`, more specifically the section [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

In this documentation, it is stated that:

> This section shows recipes for creating an extended toolset using the existing `itertools` as building blocks.
>
> Substantially all of these recipes and many, many others can be installed from the `more-itertools` project [found on the Python Package Index](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/):
>
> ```
> pip install more-itertools
> ```

If you look at [the documentation of the `more-itertools` package](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.chunked), then you will notice that the objective pursued in the question, i.e. to chunk a list, could be achieved with the following functions present in this package:

- `sliced()` to yield a list from sliceable iterables,
- `chunked()` to yield a list from non-sliceable iterables.
- `ichunked()` to yield iterables instead of lists.

For many readers who would land on this page, as they are looking for a solution which fulfills this objective, this packages offers several advantages: i) code is always up-to-date, ii) many other useful functions are present.