# How to convert a list into a matrix without numpy?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this: `A_list = [0, 5, 20, 0, 1, 8, 0, 14, 7, 5, 11, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0]`.

I want it to convert into 'matrix' form in python without using numpy.

```
A_matrix = [ [0, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0],
             [5, 1, 14, 11, 0, 0],
             [20, 8, 7, 0, 4, 0]
           ]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850536/how-to-chunk-a-list-in-python-3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to stride through the array, where each inner list starts at a different offset

```
>>> [A_list[start::3] for start in range(3)]
[[0, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0], [5, 1, 14, 11, 0, 0], [20, 8, 7, 0, 4, 0]]
```

This is basically what you'd achieve with `numpy.reshape`

```
>>> np.array(A_list).reshape((-1,3)).T
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  5,  7,  0],
       [ 5,  1, 14, 11,  0,  0],
       [20,  8,  7,  0,  4,  0]])
```